# How to continue scp transfer from last file

Tags: bash, unix, scp

I was transferring large files using scp, but I got this error:

```
write failed: Broken pipe lost connection.
```

Now I need to re-launch scp but tell it to continue from where it left off. I looked into the manpage, and couldn't figure out how to do so, and there is no interactive mode or a way to skip the files when they already exist in the destination.

Comment: You'll probably like rsync (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync)

Comment: indeed I do, I'm now using it for the first time and I already love it! Thank you very much Ivan :) (You can answer this question and your answer will be accepted :p )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I additionally suggest [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/). It offers a GUI and customizable profiles.